# Rails ordering with nil last - SQLite3 error

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, null

Currently, I am trying to order my class by the `limit` attribute. I want the values to be in ascending order, but with all `nil` values last.

I've tried a couple different queries ActiveRecord query along with a cross base SQL query (it needs to be SQL flexible). I've tried a few:

```
self.order('ISNULL(limit), limit ASC')
self.order('CASE WHEN -limit DESC')
self.order('limit IS NULL, limit DESC')
```

But I keep getting errors around `limit`, am I missing something?

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "ISNULL": syntax error: SELECT "table".*      
FROM "table"  WHERE "table"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY ISNULL(limit),   
limit ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`limit IS NULL` will do it, but `limit` is a reserved keywork in sqlite3, so enclose it in backticks or quotes:

```
self.order('`limit` IS NULL')
```

Answer (score 1):

And for anyone curious, I used `self.order("-cutoff DESC")`. It's simple and gets the job done.